# What's the different between @hide and {@hide} in Android

Tags: android

Android use the @hide can hidden a API for SDK.
but in source codes, I found two use cases:

1. /** @hide */
2. /** {@hide} */

What's the different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above example is same technically.Difference `{}` is used if you want to send some parameters to annotation. @hide annotation does not take any parameters.So in your example, both are same. But there are annotation that take parameters, like code.

`@code - doesnt take any parameters`

`{@code param}` - takes `param` as parameter for `code` annotation.

eg: `{@code string}` the string will look in code style.

Comment: Thank you !
I am still trying to found the different since all of them exist in source code even in one file.